# Make Visible a display: none with Javascript in Mobile View

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, display

I got the following code to fade in a sticky menu when a certain height is arrived and want to make it visible always from mobile view (or even better mobile devices) changing the display: none; to display: block;

The problem appears the first time that the users joins from a device less than 768px wide, the menu doesn't appear until he/she scrolls down.

I'm using the following code:

HTML

```
<nav id="menufijo" style="display:none;" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

// Everything that's inside

</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var z = $(".top-header")
        if(y > z.outerHeight() ){
          $("#menufijo").fadeIn("slow");
         } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
          $("#menufijo").style.display = "block";
        } else {
          $("#menufijo").fadeOut("fast");
        }});
</script>
```

Comment: Since your code is attached to `scroll` event it will only get executed in case user scrolls the page, I think you should move it to `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var z = $(".top-header")
    if (!window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
        if (y > z.outerHeight() ) {
            $("#menufijo").fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $("#menufijo").fadeOut("fast");
        }
    }
});
$(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches) {
        $("#menufijo").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Could you tell me why the .show works and the .style.display = "block"; doesn't?

Comment: @Kevin if you want to use the .style.display = "block" you need to acces the dom element and not the jquery object i.e you need to do $('#menufijo')[0].style.display = "block";

Comment: Thank you, I'm starting with js and will take a look on what you say.